# How do I reference a table-valued function in a common table expression?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

**Note: This issue appears to be limited to SQL Server 2005 SP2**

I have a common table expression that iterates over a series of dates. I need to reference each of these dates in a call to a table-valued function. Something like this below, which gives a syntax error around the second parameter of the call to GetMyData. If I use another value, such as @END_DATE, it works. This is the error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 17
Incorrect syntax near '.'.
```

Is there another way to do this, other than using a cursor?

```
if object_id (N'dbo.GetMyData', N'TF') is not null
    drop function dbo.GetMyData
go

create function GetMyData(@d datetime)
returns @t table (part varchar)
as
begin
    insert @t select 'a'
    insert @t select 'b'
    insert @t select 'c'

    return
end
go

declare @START_DATE datetime
declare @END_DATE datetime

set @START_DATE = '4/1/2007'
set @END_DATE = '4/11/2007'

with dates_in_range([date]) as
(
    select [date] = @START_DATE 
    union all select [date] = [date] + 1
    from dates_in_range
    where [date] < dateadd(dd,0, datediff(dd,0,@END_DATE))
)
select d.[date], c.*
from dates_in_range d
cross apply dbo.GetMyData(d.[date]) c
```

Comment: You had your '-' on the wrong tag.  Don't forget to the check the numbers next to the tag names when tagging your questions.  Low numbers==bad tags.

Comment: I cannot replicate the problem based on the posted code.  I defined a dbo.DateOnly according to your comment to rexem, and substituted a simple "split" table-valued function instead of GetMyData. Everything seems ok.  I notice your error is on line 27, but you don't have 27 lines of code posted.  Is there something else here?

Comment: Thanks for running it through. Added a more complete example. Note that after the cross apply, using dbo.GetMyData(@START_DATE) works fine, so I think the syntax is ok except for whatever doesn't work with using the referenced column.

Comment: The updated code sample runs just fine (after putting a semi-colon on the last statement before the WITH).  I would guess that your problem is inside the "real" version of dbo.GetMyData?

Comment: Thanks Chris. It seems to be isolated to a SQL 2005 issue. It definitely still gives me that error message even for the complete example I listed. I was able to run it on our SQL 2008 instance and it goes fine. Hrmph.

Comment: It is working for me on SQL 2005.  Something peculiar must be going on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the [database compatibility set to 90](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(SQL.90).aspx) for the DB on this particular instance?

The "...CROSS APPLY dbo.GetMyData(Column)..." will only work when compatibility >= 90. It fails when < 90.

**However**, "...CROSS APPLY dbo.GetMyData(@Variable)..." is accepted.

I've seen this once before, no idea why it's not consistent...

Comment: That's it. Thanks! Now I need to figure out if we can change it... bunch of old LOB apps on that database.